# Liouville's theorem for harmonic functions proof question

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, harmonic-functions

The theoerem states:

Every harmonic function on $\mathbb{C}$ which is bounded above or below is constant.

In the proof it is stated that it is sufficient to prove that every $\textit{positive}$ harmonic function is constant. Why is that the case? I can't seem to figure that out.

Comment: if $f$ is harmonic and bounded below by $C$ then $f(x)-C$ is harmonic and positive.